# L-J Potential by Scilab

Tags: scilab, computation-theory, computation

I am actually Plotting the lj potential curve for sigma=2.74 and epsilon=0.0031.Below is my code.

```
function [V,r]=lj(si,e)
     for i=1:3
            si=si*(1+(i-1)*0.1)
        r=linspace(0.75,8,1000)*si;
        V=4*e*((si./r).^12-(si./r).^6);
            subplot(2,2,1)
        plot((r/si),(V/e),'o')
            h = gca(); // get current axes
    h.data_bounds = [0.75, -2 ; 2.5, 2]
    end
    for i=1:3
            e=e*(1+(i-1)*0.3)
        r=linspace(0.75,8,1000)*si;
        V=4*e*((si./r).^12-(si./r).^6);
        subplot(2,2,2)
        plot((r/si),(V/e),'r')
        h = gca(); // get current axes
    h.data_bounds = [0.75, -2 ; 2.5, 2]
    end 
    endfunction
```

Actually in the above case i have did this for different values of sigma and epsilon but i am only getting one curve where as in the below code it works well(i.e where just there is change in the axes plot only in x and y axis). If anyone with some changes in my first code run for various value would be nice.
My working code below.

```
function [V,r]=lj(si,e)
    for i=1:3
        si=si*(1+(i-1)*0.1)
    r=linspace(0.75,8,1000);
    V=4*e*((si./r).^12-(si./r).^6);
        subplot(2,2,1)
    plot(r,V,'o')
        h = gca(); // get current axes
h.data_bounds = [2, -0.01 ; 6, 0.01]
end
    for i=1:3
        e=e*(1+(i-1)*0.3)
    r=linspace(0.75,8,1000);
    V=4*e*((si./r).^12-(si./r).^6);
    subplot(2,2,2)
    plot(r,V,'r')
    h = gca(); // get current axes
h.data_bounds = [2, -0.01 ; 6, 0.01]
end 
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

in fact in your first code si./r is equal to 1./linspace(0.75,8,1000)  and does not depends on i and the same for V and r/si!
You are just plotting 3 times the same data

Comment: It would be kind, if you make a comment on rectifying the code and comparing it with the code so it could be more clear.Moreover to your answer, actually as r doesn't as si./r doesn't depend on i as i know that's why for loop is used so that for every new value of si we will have new value.Would appreciate your discussion on this and will make clarity on it